# Complex Type in Subsonic 3

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I am going to use subsonic 3 in  a large enterprise winform application.
what i saw in my personal tests is that subsonic cannot handle complex type references well.
for example if we have an ADDRESS complex type in PERSON object , as far as i saw subsonic just created the PERSON table and is not caring about the Address property of it !

i was wondering how can i solve it ?

Secondly, we have inheritance in our objects, how subsonic can handle it with table-per-subclass strategy?

Comment: "i was wondering how can i solve it ?"  Don't fight your tool.  SubSonic will make "solving" this hard.  Better to pick a tool that fits your project better while it's still [relatively] easy.

Answer (score 1):

SubSonic isn't well suited to these scenarios. Regarding complex types you could write a service/repository to handle saving and building these types, but there's no pre-existing way of mapping this to the database.
The same goes for inheritance schemes.
You might want to look at more full-featured O/RM like NHibernate or EF.